# Really Stuck on Screen Rotation iOS 6, I Need a xib locked to portrait

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Having read every method of handling screen rotation in IOS 6 on here, Apple documents, and fierce Googling, after days and days I am still stuck on this when using xibs.

What im trying to achieve is have a few iPad only xibs, in landscape only, rest of app is portrait.

If I was using storyboards I understand how to subclass the nav controller to override the rotation but I am NOT, im using xibs and would appreciate any input how this works with xibs

In my app delegate:

```
ICHomeController *homeController = [[ICHomeController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];
navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.navigationController = navController;
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

In addition to trying what seems like every solution on here Ive tried the obvious in my vew controllers, but as I understand in iOS 6 it doesn't get called.

```
// Older versions of iOS (deprecated)
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}


 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
 }


 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
 }


 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been battling with this for days too with a more complex navigation structure.

The basic rule seems to be that the ROOT controller, whether it be a UINavigationController, UITabBarController or just a simple UIViewController, takes control of the rotation. So as you PUSH UIViewControllers onto the stack, the very first one still controls the rotation.

If you use a modal view, then this model view will be considered the ROOT of the stack until it is dismissed. So if you show a modal UIViewController then push views on top of it, the UIViewController that was presented as the modal view is in control of the rotation.
Just make sure for modal views to use presentViewController:animated:completion.

The easiest way to get certain views to be in a different rotation, is present it modally.
If this can't be avoided, then go right back to your first view or nag controller and set the rotations.

Add some `NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);` statements to your rotation methods to see which ones are being called.

In your code above, only the first method is the old iOS5 (Now deprecated) method. The other 3 are the new iOS 6 methods.

Using your example code above, you would need to subclass the UINavigationController. To do this create a new class as a UINavigationController subclass with a different name eg. MyNavigationController and add the rotation methods to it. Then in your code above instead of using
`UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];`

You would use:

`MyNavigationController *navController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];`

Also, make sure you have allowed orientations selected here:
[image]

Comment: Nothing is being called I added the logs early on in the process, im supporting iOS 5 and 6 hence the deprecated method still there.  The app is complex and not my code, and really cant work this out. Im using my rotation cod ein my root view controller as its pushed on the stack, I simply cannot get any acknowledgement of those methods.  Whilst I undertand in principal, and can do it in storyboards, working with xibs its just not having it.  Thanks for update answer let me try that out...

Comment: Your viewController isn't the root, the navController is. So the navController must be subclassed to get rotation to work.

Comment: That makes sense, now ive sublassed my nav controller thanks to your advice (plus 1 for you) still not getting screen rotation, there must be an easier way than this!

Comment: Have you put NSLog's in to see if the methods are called in the subclassed nav controller?

Comment: Also, in your code you have this `self.navigationController = navController;
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];` Surely that should just be `window.rootViewController = navController;`

Comment: yes ns log `2012-12-23 19:21:05.800 iCertifi[2530:907] -[navLandscapeViewController shouldAutorotate]
2012-12-23 19:21:05.802 iCertifi[2530:907] -[navLandscapeViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]` so its being called at least!

Comment: Not sure about `window.rootViewController = navController` just get errors trying any otehr way

Comment: Progress. Thats the first step :-) Now do you have the correct allowed orientations as in the image above?

Comment: Also, what is self.navigationController? Is it a different UINavigationController that this one is on top of?

Comment: Im getting exited progress indeed! ive also checked its not just the ios 5 being called, iOS 5 & 6 being called :-)  Yes correct orientations as per your pic. I think `self.navigationController` may be on the top thinking about it, it pushes views from an alert view.

Comment: If its on the top, and your adding another nav controller to it, then it's that original one that needs subclassing to do the rotation.

Comment: And dont forget, in this subclass you need to support all the orientations that the stacked views will need which may be both landscape and portrait. You just have to use if's to separate them depending on what class the topViewController is

Comment: Im still not getting anywhere with this, everything is just controlled by either the delegate method or supported orientations option in summary, and  just cant override these. Thanks so much for you help, I think im going to have to think of some other way of approaching this as its been days now and I still cant get it to work.  Thanks again

Comment: The easiest way it to show the view using `[self presentViewController:animated:completion];` method. Then the rotation methods will work from the ViewController itself

Comment: Thanks, im picking up someone else code here and just have no idea what going re: navigation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Here's what worked for me in 5 and 6.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0)
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

In terms of the target summary, only portrait mode is "supported".